# Are running processes ever put into a sleep/wait queue automatically by the kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

As I understand it, running processes (and drivers etc) get put into a wait queue when they need to wait for a resource that may not be available yet. I know this can be done by manually invoking the kernel and putting yourself into the wait queue until the resource becomes available.

So my question is: Are any processes ever put into the wait queue without the code explicitly entering itself into it? And, if so, how does the kernel determine that the process actually needs to be put into the wait queue or wants to wait on a resource instead of continuing execution without it etc?

Mainly asking in relation to linux, but if something similar is done in some other kernel/operating system I would be equally interested in knowing how.

Comment: The timer tick interrupt will reschedule processes.

Comment: @stark Are you saying the process can be put it into the wait queue during that? I already know the timer tick interrupt reschedules processes and context switches based on priority level etc, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: If a process uses up its time slice and there are other runnable processes then yes.

Comment: @stark Wouldn't that just put it back into the run queue and possibly change priority levels?

Comment: Maybe you're right.  I think it stays on run queue if it is still marked runnable.  I thought it would wait for a timer tick, but that might be my bad memory.

Comment: I think while in kernel context, the task needs to do something sleepable before it can be put back on the run queue. If it just sits there in a tight loop, it will just hang there. The scheduler will complain to the kernel log about the task being stuck.

Comment: @IanAbbott Do you mean if it's currently in the sleep queue? To clarify, when I said "back to the run queue" I meant going from the cpu running in the context of the process1,  and then process2 with higher priority might take its place, putting process1 "back into the queue".

I might be using wrong terms though, if it technically doesn't leave the queue when becoming the active process.

Comment: "Are any processes ever put into the wait queue without the code explicitly entering itself into it?" - No, there is no such functionality.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you!

Comment: @STB I meant the run queue because "do something sleepable" just means do something that _might_ cause the task to sleep. Also, I think what I described only applies when CONFIG_PREEMPT is not defined. For CONFIG_PREEMPT, the task can be put back on the run queue at any time as long as the task is currently preemptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is: Are any processes ever put into the wait queue without the code explicitly entering itself into it?

There isn't one wait queue ("the wait queue" vs. "a wait queue").

Instead, you can expect some kind of data structure (e.g. wait queue) for each resources that a task could be waiting for - e.g. maybe one for each mutex, one for each pipe, one for each network socket, etc. Also, for modern kernels (designed for lots of CPUs) it relatively common to have even more wait queues to improve scalability and lock contention - e.g. for something like time ("sleep()") you might have one queue per CPU (instead of one global queue that all CPUs share).

Of course it's not that simple either. A wait queue might not be a queue and could be something else (e.g. a tree); and (within reason) there can be multiple resources associated with a wait queue (e.g. instead of one for each separate pipe you might use a hash table approach and always have 4096 queues regardless of how many pipes there are).

> So my question is: Are any processes ever put into the wait queue without the code explicitly entering itself into it?

Yes. There are 2 cases where this is extremely likely:

a) the scheduler (when tasks are waiting for CPU time) will have some kind of "wait something" (tree? List for each thread priority?). This isn't much different to any other case - a CPU is just another resource, and waiting for CPU is just waiting for a resource.

b) virtual memory tricks. For example, if a process needs to wait until data is fetched from swap space (or from a memory mapped file, or ..) then the process will be put on some kind of "wait something".

Answer (score 0):

No, @Tsyvarev is correct. Linux will not move a process to a wait-queue without the process explicitly performing an operation that results in being moved to a wait-queue.

For example, if a process requests IO, then it may be placed on the wait-queue associated with the IO device while the IO is performed. It is also possible that the IO request immediately returns if, for example, the OS has already cached a file that the process wants to read, or if the OS is buffering a request to write.

Waiting on a condition variable is another example of a request that would cause a process to be moved to a wait-queue associated with that condition variable.